# integration of simple function

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have  this question I saw this week which I do not understand the answer for it.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R} a <b \ $ and let $f_1:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I know that $\int_a^x \mathrm{f_1(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x \in \mathbb{R} \  \forall x \in [a,b]$

I also that $\forall k\in \mathbb{N} \ f_k:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

and that $ f_{k+1}(x) = \int_a^x \mathrm{f_{k}(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t$

So I know that the series is defined well.

now I have to proof that $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} f_{k+1}(x)$ is uniform convergence.

So I know that $\exists M \in \mathbb{N}\ \forall x\in [a,b] \ |f_{1}(x)| \leq M $

Therefore I can conclude that $ \forall x\in [a,b] \ |f_{2}(x)| \leq M(x-a)$

And therefore I can conclude that

$\forall x\in [a,b] \ |f_3(x)| = |\int_a^x \mathrm{f_{2}(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t|\leq |\int_a^x \mathrm{M(x-a)}\,\mathrm{d}t| = \frac{M(x-a)^{2}}{2}\leq M(x-a)^{2} $

My question is this:

from what I learned about integration I can say that

because  $|\int_a^x \mathrm{M(x-a)}\,\mathrm{d}t| = | M(x-a) \int_a^x \mathrm{}\,\mathrm{d}t| = | M(x-a)(x-a)| =    M(x-a)^{2} $

And not that :

$ |\int_a^x \mathrm{M(x-a)}\,\mathrm{d}t|= \frac{M(x-a)^{2}}{2}\leq M(x-a)^{2}$

So what am I missing here ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: You've to pay attention to the name of your variables. You know that $|f_2(x)|\le M(x-a)$ then $\left|\int_a^x f_2(t)dt\right| \le \int_a^x M(t-a)dt$.